# Gradle screwed up my app in AndroidStudio, how to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on a new app in AndroidStudio, everything was working fine, I was testing the app on my phone, etc.
Then at some point AndroidStudio gave me a popup in the lower right corner, something about Gradle. I didn't quite understand it, and hit Accept or something like that. Then suddenly something happened to all my projects in AndroidStudio (not just the one I was working on):

- All build modules are gone.
- I can't make any new build modules, because "Error: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again". I never synced anything with Gradle previously, why do I suddenly need to do something like this?
- Clicking "Sync project with Gradle files" doesn't work: "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources". Where does "com.android.application" even come from? I never added any plugins anywhere.
- "Everything" is wrong in all my Java files, I even get "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'" and "Cannot resolve method 'OnCreate(android.os.Bundle)'". Wtf?
- All my Java files have this red symbol, which says "Java file outside of source root". Why are they suddenly in the wrong place?

Nothing is working anymore, restarting AndroidStudio doesn't change anything, switching project doesn't change anything, and where did my build modules go?
How do I make this go back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `Build` -> `Clean Project` and then `Build` again
2. `File` -> `Invalidate cache/restart`
3. check your `run/debug` configuration in the top toolbar, it should be `app` by default.

[image]